# AWS IoT guarantee delivery

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-iot

I am starting with AWS IoT service with Raspberry Pi as a device. And I do not understand how I can make guarantee delivery for my data to AWS IoT MQTT service.

There are two cases:

1. The device has no Internet connection but powered on. In this case, I can use in-memory store (offline queue from AWS SDK library).
2. The device is powered off. In this case, I am losing my data in RAM.

How to save my data without running some database engine on Raspberry. 
Do you have some best practices?

Comment: In addition to answer below, if you are worried about publishing messages and offline device not receiving, iot device shadow is your friend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to somehow save your data to disk to mitigate issue #2. The best practice is to use an established database system. SqLite is a very lightweight database. They are not that hard to use, give it a shot! If you really hate that idea, you could just save the data in json format to a text file. That works as well.